# Simple vs. Nested

Tags: loops, nested-loops, turing-complete

Are simple loops as powerful as nested loops in terms of Turing completeness?

Comment: What do you mean by 'powerful'?

Comment: What do you mean by 'as powerful'? As for expressibility, both are equivalent - you'll may need to adjust your data structures.

Comment: care about editing your question, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of Turing completeness, yes they are.

Proof: It's possible to write a [Brainf***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter using a simple loop, for example here:

http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/sbi.c

Comment: Any available reference with proofs? Under what assumptions?

Comment: Thanks for the example, however, it's still using an inner while loop inside the main one. But I am seeking a formal proof, if you can help with any references that might help.

Comment: @banx: Yeah that interpreter I linked to was badly written. But it's fairly trivial to write a Brainfuck interpret using only a simple loop - the concept is straightforward: move the instruction pointer, do what it says, repeat until you reach the end.

Comment: Finally found one that doesn't use nested loops: http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/sbi.c

Answer (score 0):

For loops with a fixed number of steps (LOOP, FOR and similar): Imagine the whole purpose of a loop is to count to `n`. Why should make it a difference if I loop `i` times in an outer loop and `j` times in an inner loop as opposed `n = i * j` in just a single loop?

Assume that no WHILE, GOTO or similar constructs are allowed in a program (just assignment, IF, and fixed loops). Then all these programs end after a finite number of steps.

The next step to more expressibility is to allow loops, where the number of iterations is e.g. determined by a condition, and it is not sure, whether this condition is ever satisfied (e.g. WHILE). Then is may happen, that a program won't halt. (This type of expressiveness is also known as [Turing-completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)).

Corresponding to these two forms of programs are two kinds of functions, which were historically developed around the same time and which are called [primitive recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) and [μ-recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-recursive_function).

The number of nestings doesn't play a role in this.

Comment: You are assuming a very simple scenario where loops simply count a fixed amount of steps. In general, internal variables affect the stopping conditions of loops.